# How does Mutter/Window Groups work in Gnome?

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

the Shelltile-Extension for Gnome 3 (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/ where you also find a link to github) can group Windows such that they are treated as one by Gnome.

I would like to understand how this is done since it looks like something that might be useful for me...

A look at the source code suggests that the magic is hidden in the javascript library imports.gi.Meta, which points me to Mutter and Gnome, but their documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/meta/stable/core-reference.html) isn't very helpful for someone new to the topic, or at least for me... has anyone more information?

(Of course, it might be that I looked at the wrong part of the source code and I might looking in the wrong direction... anyhow, any help is appreciated!)